# Trying to connect to a server on my network

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

I was trying to connect to a server that is running on another pc in my house. I've tried all the other ip's in the ipconfig in the cmd and doesn't work. I need help with this. When I try to join using the external ip it just times out the server is port forwarded. I've had other people join to test to see if they can get in and they can but I can't.

Comment: You can just look at your network connection properties to get your IP address.

Comment: If you're running Windows: Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center and then click on your connection (left click) it should pop open a window full of numbers. one says IPv4 address, that should be your guy. It should probably be 192.168.xxx.xxx

Comment: Oh, btw you should search the site before posting questions. You would've found your solution as this has been asked a few times.

Comment: Thats why im making a new question none of those ip's work

Comment: I already tried the Ipv4 one

Comment: I cant connect to the server when its running on the other pc

Comment: Can anybody connect to it from any computer including from the computer that runs the server???

Comment: The server pc cannot connect to the server but other players can

Comment: but the non server pc cant connect too

Comment: So you have random people who can't connect....well, this isn't going anywhere

Comment: No randoms can connect

Comment: but every pc at my house cant

Comment: 162.226.244.84:25561 if you want to try

Comment: So everybody on the outside of your lan can connect, everybody behind the router can't and this is the same router as the server runs on? Have you tried connecting to the public ip then? Thats how I connect to my home server. Also, you may need to be on the same workgroup/homegroup as well.

Comment: Yes even if i do localhost on the server pc it dosent work they all have the same router nad the public ip just times me out

Comment: I was accually able to log on as localhost:25561 on the server pc

Answer (score 1):

**Easiest way:**

Make sure both computers are connected to the same network.

1. Log into your MC world.
2. Hit 'esc' on your keyboard.
3. Click 'Open to LAN'
4. Adjust settings and click 'Start LAN World'

Go to the other computer.

1. Click 'Multiplayer' on the home screen.
2. Select the world that you opened in the last 4 steps.

---

*If the world doesn't show up:*

1. Go back to the other computer.
2. Open up CMD ([WinKey/Start] and type 'cmd')
3. Type 'ipconfig' and search for IPv4 address
4. Copy it down and go to the other computer.
5. In the 'Multiplayer' menu, click 'Direct Connect'
6. Type the IPv4 Address and click 'join server'.

   ---

Also check all firewalls and restrictions on your network.

---

**Other Way:**

**Making a public server is too much to explain. Just look it up.**